# Does the expectation of a quantile equal to the quantile of expectations?

Tags: probability, quantiles, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ be a random variable with finite expectation $E(X)$, and let's denote $X_{90}$ the 90% quantile of its distribution, meaning:
$$P(X<X_{90})=0.9$$
Now, let Y be another random variable and

- let $E(X|Y)$ be the conditional expectation of $X$ given $Y$. By definition, this conditional expectation is also a random variable.
- let $E(X|Y)_{90}$ be the 90% quantile of $E(X|Y)$, meaning
  $$P(E(X|Y)<E(X|Y)_{90})=0.9$$

Does the following equality hold?

$$X_{90}=E(X|Y)_{90}$$

In other-words, does a "law of total quantiles" exist like the Law of Total Expectation?

Comment: Test the following example: let $Y$ be a Bernoulli random variable. Next, let $X \sim \mathsf{Unif}(0,2Y+1)$. Does your proposed equality hold?

Comment: No - $X$ and $E(X \mid Y)$ have the same expectation but $X$ usually has a higher variance (certainly not smaller) so you should not expect the quantiles to be the same.

Comment: Perhaps it would be more interesting to ask if there are any counterexamples to $X_{90}\ge E(X\mid Y)_{90}$

Comment: $\mathbb E[X|Y]_{90}$ is in general a random variable, as a function of $Y$, while $X_{90}$ is not.